# Is there a keyboard shortcut to fold all of the code at once in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, code-folding

i have big code in every file in my project and i need a shortcut to reduce the whole code in specific file with one click instead of doing it manual

i have taken screenshot to explain it

[image]

in my case i am clicking manual to every single line and every time I am restarting android studio it expanded again I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fold:

Mac: `Shift` + `⌘ command` + `-`

Windows/Linux: `Shift` + `CTRL` + `-`

To unfold:

Mac: `Shift` + `⌘ command` + `+`

Windows/Linux: `Shift` + `CTRL` + `+`

Comment: i noticed it also folding the Subcodes .. is there a way to fold only the whole parents of any Subcodes

Comment: This is a good reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Folding.html (Android Studio is based on JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA)